# Hyper does the same as super by default

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

Under the keyboard → layouts → options, one has the ability to 'Make caps lock an additional hyper'.  This is a good feature because I personally abhor caps lock and like additional shortcuts.  Unfortunately, I shortly discovered that hyper is set by default to do the same as super.  This makes it annoying when hyper opens dash.  Under `xmodmap`, one sees that hyper and super are both set to the modifier `mod4` and nothing is set to `mod3`.  I did some research to fix it and it is easily fixed by making a file called `.xmodmaprc` in `~` with:
'`clear mod3`
`clear mod4`
`add mod4 = Super_L`
`add mod4 = Super_R`
`add mod3 = Hyper_L`' in it.
However, I would like to know why hyper is not set to `mod3` by default.  Is there any advantage to this?  Furthermore, if there is no adequate reason, is it possible that this may be fixed in the future?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards